# Unicorn crashing because of using wrong ruby version after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, unicorn

I am having trouble launching my application in the server because of the following error:

```
/home/blabla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn", "-E", "beta", "-c", "/var/www/testenvir/releases/20141117005244/config/unicorn.rb", "-D", {16=>#<Kgio::UNIXServer:fd 16>}] (in /var/www/testenvir/releases/20141121053734)

/home/blabla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:390:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.1.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

The error is self descritive, but i don't know how to fix it since i have in my Gemfile script:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
```

And in my capistrano deployment script:

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-2.0.0-p353'
set :bundle_dir, "/home/blabla/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin"
```

In my server, i set my environment variables as following:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353
```

And the output of env RAILS_ENV=testenvir bundle exec ruby -v is :

```
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]
```

I could verify by connecting through a new terminal that `rvm list`produces :

```
=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
```

Finally my crashing command is defined in the eye script that tries launching the following command:

```
bundle exec unicorn -E #{RAILS_ENV} -c #{working_dir}/config/unicorn.rb -D
```

I verified that #{working_directory} and #{RAILS_ENV} are correct, so i thought about hardcoding ( as a first step), the paths of `bundle`and `unicorn`, since they are the one taken from the 2.1.0 instead of the 2.0.0-p353 ( The error that i get in unicorn.log... ), but it didn't work ( crashed with another error...)

I also checked $PATH, $GEM_HOME, $GEM_PATH and $RUBY_VERSION, and they were all pointing to the version 2.0.0-p353. In fact, i did a printenv and looked for a potential variable with ruby-2.1.0 assigned to it, but i found none !

I checked all files of my application to wether i am assigning ruby-2.1.0 somewhere anyhow, but i didn't find any reference to that. All of them were set to ruby-2.0.0-p353.

My question is :

Is there another place that i am missing where should i specify my desired ruby version ? How should i set my ruby version in the server rather that what i did ?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

```
rvm current 
ruby-2.0.0-p353

rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p353 (found in /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353)
=> (default)
   global
```

Comment: please show output of `bundle exec ruby -V`

Comment: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]. I edited the question to add this output

Comment: ok then `bundle exec which unicorn`

Comment: The error shows you are using the ruby 2.1 gemset, that's likely the only problem.  Switching to 2.0 gemset should solve this issue.  Can you check the currently selected gemset using `rvm current`, list all available gemsets using `rvm gemset list` select a gemset using `rvm gemset use ...`.

Comment: @ Малъ: /home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn

Comment: how did you run the command `bundle exec unicorn -E #{RAILS_ENV} -c #{working_dir}/config/unicorn.rb -D`? from root etc?

Comment: I have a special user for deployment. He has the necessary permissions to run the eye commands...

Comment: I didn't have any problem before trying to change the ruby version in use... (Which i need to do in my case) But before, it was working without a problem...

Answer (score 1):

A little late but could help others who are experiencing the same problem. I´m using rolling restart and what helped me was this comment which I have in my config/unicorn.rb file

```
    # If you roll off old code from your app servers (i.e. the way chef, capistrano, 
    # basically anyone does it) you need to make sure Unicorn is not looking for 
    # the Gemfile it was originally started with. It's really important that after 
    # change you stop/start unicorn after first redeploy.
    # After that the "before_exec" block will go in memory and 
    # wait for the next deploy!
    before_exec do |server|
      ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{root}/Gemfile"
    end
```

So then I ran

/etc/init.d/unicorn-myapp stop

/etc/init.d/unicorn-myapp start

and unicorn picked up the new ruby version.